# How to retrieve data from Umbraco by route to model?

Tags: umbraco

I got the node

```
   var l=  UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache.GetByRoute("1080/companies")
```

The node is list of doctype company

How to serialize the node to list of company class that in all.generated.cs ??

Answer (score 0):

It should already be of type Company. You should be able to just cast it to your model type, e.g something like:

```
var l =  UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache.GetByRoute("1080/companies") as Company;
```

Or

```
var l =  (Company)UmbracoContext.Current.ContentCache.GetByRoute("1080/companies");
```

Assuming that the generated class is called Company.

Comment: Does the route actually return an IPublishedContent object, or null? E.g. if you remove the casting bit.